# Running Chrome with and without CLI flags on OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is it possible to run Chrome on OSX with command line flags like `--ignore-certificate-errors`, and at the same time run another instance of Chrome without those flags enabled without using something like Canary? I like using Chrome as my primary browser, but don't want to have certain flags I sometimes use for dev running when I'm browsing the web,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do it on the commandline.

```
open -n -a "Google Chrome" --args --user-data-dir=/tmp/chrome/ --ignore-certificate-errors
```

To open a independent instance of chrome you need to define a separate userdata directory. `/tmp/chrome` is just an example.